# dynamic switching between two kafkaTemplate objects

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have two kafka clusters (Active-passive). 
I created two KafkaTemplate objects for producing events(one for each). 
I will keep using primary kafkaTemplate to send events as long as it is healthy. Incase of any issue, i want to dynamically switch over to  second kafkaTemplate.
I dont want to have an if condition to switch between objects to use to send( last resort)

Is there a way to dynamically switch objects?

*Consumer side, we have MessageListenerContainers and we have setAutoStartUp api to manage start and stop of multiple listeners*

Can someone help me with the producer?!

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement your own `KafkaOperations` which delegates to active template and fails over when needed.

**EDIT**

For example:

```java
public class DelegatingTemplate<K, V> implements KafkaOperations<K, V> {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template1;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template2;

    private volatile KafkaTemplate<String, String> currentTemplate;

    public DelegatingTemplate(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template1, KafkaTemplate<String, String> template2) {
        this.template1 = template1;
        this.template2 = template2;
        this.currentTemplate = template1;
    }

    public void switchTemplates(boolean primary) {
        this.currentTemplate = primary ? template1 : template2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransactional() {
        return this.currentTemplate.isTransactional();
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendDefault(String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.sendDefault(data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendDefault(String key, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.sendDefault(key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendDefault(Integer partition, String key, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.sendDefault(partition, key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendDefault(Integer partition, Long timestamp, String key,
            String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.sendDefault(partition, timestamp, key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(String topic, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(topic, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(String topic, String key, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(topic, key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(String topic, Integer partition, String key, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(topic, partition, key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(String topic, Integer partition, Long timestamp,
            String key, String data) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(topic, partition, timestamp, key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(ProducerRecord<String, String> record) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(record);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> send(Message<?> message) {
        return this.currentTemplate.send(message);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PartitionInfo> partitionsFor(String topic) {
        return this.currentTemplate.partitionsFor(topic);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric> metrics() {
        return this.currentTemplate.metrics();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(ProducerCallback<String, String, T> callback) {
        return this.currentTemplate.execute(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T executeInTransaction(OperationsCallback<String, String, T> callback) {
        return this.currentTemplate.executeInTransaction(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.currentTemplate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        this.currentTemplate.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendOffsetsToTransaction(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets) {
        this.currentTemplate.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsets);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendOffsetsToTransaction(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, String consumerGroupId) {
        this.currentTemplate.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsets, consumerGroupId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with sample java spring snippets?